# django - split up urls.py into multiple

Tags: python, django

I know, this is actually basics of django BUT

I tried to split my huge urls.py into 3 pieces. All 3 urls_xxx.py live under one folder: `mysite`.

then in main urls.py i did:

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns += patterns('',

    url(r'^', include('urls_search')),
    url(r'^', include('urls_ajax')),
    url(r'^', include('urls_sitemaps')),

)
```

but it is saying:

```
ImportError at /
No module named urls_search
```

this is urls_search.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^advancedsearch/$', 'advsearch', name="advsearch"),
    url(r'^advancedsearch/tc/$', 'advtcsearch', name="advtcsearch"),
)
```

my URLCONF:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

what am I doing wrong? I am using Django 1.4

Comment: If you are using include, make sure you have ____init____.py in mysite folder :)

Comment: @ruddra basically, mysite folder always has the *__init__.py*, because it has settings.py alongside. ;)

Comment: well, um ... I have checked include's source code, it took a string as parameter which is suppose to indicate a urlconf existing in a module. I am not sure, but I think its indicating either app folder  or a package. If your folder has an init and I am guessing your url_xxx.py has urlconf (like urlpatterns= patterns(..)), I think you should put your urls_xxx.py in app directory and test if it works. :)

Comment: @ruddra yeah, you are right, this is also what i am thinking right now. i have to say, thank you so much for your time and effort to help me.

Answer (score 6):

remove `.py` like this:

```
url(r'^', include('mysite.urls_search')),
```

Comment: i removed ``.py`` from my question as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this in main 'urls.py':

```
from mysites.url_1 import urlpatterns as url1
from mysites.url_2 import urlpatterns as url2
from mysites.url_3 import urlpatterns as url3

urlpatterns = url1
urlpatterns += url2
urlpatterns += url3
```

Answer (score -1):

In **main url.py**

```
from mysites import url1
from mysites import url2
from mysites import url3

urlpatterns = url1.urlpatterns
urlpatterns += url2.urlpatterns
urlpatterns += url3.urlpatterns
```

and so on

Comment: This is literally the same as all other answers.

Comment: Yes it is... but little different way to do the same. In case newbie might feel hard to understand above, this might suffice the problem to their level of understanding.